# Children's science fiction show from the early 90s, where a man's soul is sent to earth, and ends up in a mannequin

Tags: story-identification, tv

I can remember very few details regarding this show.

I believe it aired on the children's channel in the early '90s and was an Australian production.

The show itself was about people on another world, one man was injured and his spirit/soul was transported to earth. Several people from his world came to earth to bring him back.

If I recall it ended that his spirit was inside a mannequin.

Comment: It's probably not [*The Journey of Allen Strange*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Journey_of_Allen_Strange) right?

Comment: It wasn't a show called Today's Special was it ?